# Link error while Compiling CUDA from command prompt

Tags: linker, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to compile a CUDA test program on Windows 7 x64 via Command Prompt using this command:

```
nvcc cuda.cu
```

I get the following output and then this error message:

```
cuda.cu
tmpxft_00000d14_00000000-3_cuda.cudafe1.gpu
tmpxft_00000d14_00000000-8_cuda.cudafe2.gpu
cuda.cu
tmpxft_00000d14_00000000-3_cuda.cudafe1.cpp
tmpxft_00000d14_00000000-14_cuda.ii
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

I have the kernel.lib file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib and adding that to the CUDA lib environment variable doesn't work.

What would be causing this error and how do I rectify it?

Comment: Try adding "-machine 32" as an argument

Comment: Tried it @Jay It says 
    nvcc fatal   : 'achine': expected a number.
Then tried "--machine 32" still gives,
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Comment: How about -m64 since you are on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Tried it @harrism It gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: @harrism No. I am a beginner and am learning to write simple code for CUDA. That is why I started with the command prompt.

Comment: Actually you need a host compiler to build CUDA code, so even with a correct library location you might not be able to build. See the CUDA release notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not specify the MS lib location in an environment variable.  You need to use a '-L' command line option as in

```
nvcc <file> -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib"
```

Really you probably need Visual Studio installed because you need a host compiler to build your host code.

Comment: Ohk. I installed Visual Studio Express Edition. While running from the command line, it gives a lot of errors! Here are a few of them..
    LIBCMT.lib(commit.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLastError
    LIBCMT.lib(lseeki64.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLastError referenced in function _lseeki64_nolock
    LIBCMT.lib(close.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLastError
    LIBCMT.lib(osfinfo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetLastError

    a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 76 unresolved externals

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 10.0 Express and the Windows SDK 7.1 and I did not get the errors you get.  However, I was not able to get it to compile 64-bit (the default with a 64-bit CUDA Toolkit).  I did get it to compile with no errors by adding `--machine 32`.  To compile without that option, I had to install Visual Studio 10.0 Professional.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. I have moved to MacOSX now and am able to compile and run codes using nvcc.